# What causes this difference in behaviour for malloc() and free() between Windows and Linux?

Tags: c, linux, windows, malloc, free

I am trying to dynamically allocate a 2D array the following way:

0. Have a pointer checker.

```html
void chk (void* p) {
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate.\n");
        exit (0);
    }
}
```

1. Read the number of lines.

```html
scanf("%d", &n);
```

2. Allocate the necessary memory for the array of arrays (`v`), and for the array that keeps the sizes of the lines (`u`).

```html
v = (int**) calloc(n, sizeof(int));
chk(v);
u = (int*) calloc(n, sizeof(int));
chk(u);
```

3. For each line, read the number of elements in it (`u[i]`). Allocate the necessary memory for the current line (`v[i]`), and read the elements.

```html
scanf("%d", &u[i]);
v[i] = (int*) calloc(u[i], sizeof(int));
chk(v[i]);
for (j = 0; j < u[i]; j++)
    scanf("%d", &v[i][j]);
```

4. Print the values stored in `u`.

```html
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d\n", u[i]);
```

5. Free the memory.

```html
free(u);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    free(v[i]);
free(v);
```

[This code](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/coCG6dzs41) runs correctly in Windows (*with the free section uncommented*), but fails to do so in Linux! Upon running the code in an online compiler (so under Linux), we could see two things:

1. u[0] is garbage, and u[1] is 0.

   u[2], ..., u[n] are okay.
2. With the free section commented, **1.** is possible. However, if free isn't commented, we would get the `Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)`.

How are the last two points possible? What causes the difference between Windows and Linux? How can it be fixed?

Thank you!

Comment: `v = (int**) calloc(n, sizeof(int))` is wrong because `sizeof(int)` is not guaranteed to be equal to `sizeof(*int)` (platform dependent), so it is likely to cause UB

Comment: Notice anything odd about this line? `v = (int**) calloc(n, sizeof(int));` What are you allocating here? What if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int*)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem:

```
v = (int**) calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

Is `v` supposed to be an array of `int` or `int *`?  Your cast and `sizeof` operands don’t agree.  The best way to fix this is to lose the cast and to use `sizeof *v` as your size:

```
v = calloc( n, sizeof *v );
```

Do the same for the allocations of `u` and each `v[i]` - the general idiom is

```
T *p = calloc( n, sizeof *p );
```

or

```
T *p;
...
p = calloc( n, sizeof *p );
```

Unless you are compiling this code as C++ or pre-C89, the cast on the return value of `calloc` is unnecessary and counterproductive.